# Cannot echo database items

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo out some database items in php but nothing seems to be coming out. The initialize php that is required calls out the database.php that stores all the configurations as show below.What am I doing wrong?

SQL statement:

```
<?php
require_once("includes/initialize.php");

$userName = $_POST["name"];
$userEmail = $_POST["email"];

$sqlName = "SELECT name FROM individual";
$sqlEmail = "SELECT email FROM individual";

if ($sqlEmail == $userEmail || $sqlName == $userName){

$message = "Hi " + $userName + "this is your new password.";

echo $message;

}

?>
```

The database configurations are in another php file called database.php.

database.php:

```
<?php

require_once ("config.php");

 class MySQLDatabase {

private $connection;

function __construct() {
    $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME) or die
                    ("Database connection failed: " .
                    mysqli_connect_error() .
                    " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
    );
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($this->connection, DB_NAME);
}

public function close_connection() {
    if (isset($this->connection)) {
        mysqli_close($this->connnection);
        unset($this->connection);
    }
}

public function query($sql) {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
    $this->confirm_query($result);
    return $result;
}

private function confirm_query($result) {
    if (!$result) {
        die("Database query failed.");
    }
}

public function escape_value($string) {

    $escaped_string = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->connection, $string);
    return $escaped_string;
}

public function fetch_array($id){
    if (mysqli_fetch_array($id)) {
        return true;
    } 
    }
    }

    $database = new MySQLDatabase();
    $db = & $database;
    ?>
```

Comment: You just compare strings here, and never execute your select statements against the database

Answer (score 0):

Your not running your query..  ..or getting its results..

```
$sqlEmail = "SELECT email FROM individual";

$query = $db->query($sqlEmail);

$user = $db->fetch_array($query);

var_dumpr($user);
```

Hope this helps..